# Visualforce Error System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 0

Tags: apex, visualforce

Can any one help me out with this Error ??I have records created in  the object.Any help is much appreciated

```
Visualforce Error

System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 0 
Class.QuoteContentController.<init>: line 234, column 1
```

This is the Error line

```
QtyGrndTtl[j] = Qrtr1QtyGrndTtl + Qrtr2QtyGrndTtl + Qrtr3QtyGrndTtl + Qrtr4QtyGrndTtl;
```

Code :

```
    public with sharing class QuoteContentController {
    public Map < String, Decimal > PartMap {get;set;}
    public Map < string, Decimal > Quarter1 {get;set;}  
    public Map < string, Decimal > Quarter2 {get;set;}  
    public Map < string, Decimal > Quarter3 {get;set;}  
    public Map < string, Decimal > Quarter4 {get;set;}  
    public Map < string, Decimal > Amount1 {get;set;}  
    public Map < string, Decimal > Amount2 {get;set;}  
    public Map < string, Decimal > Amount3 {get;set;}  
    public Map < string, Decimal > Amount4 {get;set;}  
    public Competitor__c com {get;set;}  
    public gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c opflist {get;set;}  
    public Id qId {get;set;}  
    Public string all {get;set;}  

    Public QuoteContentController() {}
    Public QuoteContentController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        qId = Apexpages.currentPage().getparameters().get('Id');
    }
        Public Integer subtotalofquantity{get;set;}    

        Public Integer subtotalofamount{get;set;}

        Public Integer Colquarter1subtotal{get;set;}  
        Public Integer quarter2subtotal{get;set;}  

        Public integer Qrtr1QtyGrndTtl =  0;
        Public integer Qrtr2QtyGrndTtl =  0;
        Public integer Qrtr3QtyGrndTtl =  0;
        Public integer Qrtr4QtyGrndTtl =  0;
        list<integer>QtyGrndTtl = new list<integer>();

        Public decimal Qrtr1AmtGrndTtl =  0;
        Public decimal Qrtr2AmtGrndTtl =  0;
        Public decimal Qrtr3AmtGrndTtl =  0;
        Public decimal Qrtr4AmtGrndTtl =  0;
        list<decimal>AmtGrndTtl = new list<decimal>();  



        Public List<wrapperClass> disp_list {get;set;}{
        subtotalofquantity = 0;
        subtotalofamount = 0;
        Colquarter1subtotal = 0;
        quarter2subtotal = 0;

        integer Qrtr1QtyGrndTtl =  0;
        integer Qrtr2QtyGrndTtl =  0;
        integer Qrtr3QtyGrndTtl =  0;
        integer Qrtr4QtyGrndTtl =  0;


       decimal Qrtr1AmtGrndTtl =  0;
       decimal Qrtr2AmtGrndTtl =  0;
       decimal Qrtr3AmtGrndTtl =  0;
       decimal Qrtr4AmtGrndTtl =  0;




        disp_list = new list < wrapperclass > ();
        //Query all the list     
        List < Quote > q = [select id, Name, QuoteNumber, Effective_Date__c, Comments__c, Quote.Opportunity.id,
                                    Quote.Opportunity.Probability, Quote.Opportunity.AccSegment__c, 
                                    Quote.Opportunity.AccApplication__c, Quote.Opportunity.Persona__c, Quote.Opportunity.Region__c
                                    from Quote where id = : apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id')];
        Opportunity opp = [select id, Name, (select id, Quantity, product2id from OpportunityLineItems), 
                                probability, AccSegment__c 
                                from Opportunity where opportunity.Id = : q[0].opportunity.id LIMIT 1];
        List < gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c > opflist = [
                                Select id, Name, gmod__opportunity__r.id, gmod__Quantity__c, gmod__Price__c,
                                gmod__Month__c, gmod__date__c, gmod__Quarter__c, gmod__Amount__c, Actual_Price__c, 
                                gmod__Year__c, gmod__Month_Text__c, Forecast_Date__c, gmod__Product__r.Name, 
                                gmod__opportunity__r.name from gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c 
                                WHERE gmod__Product__c != null and gmod__opportunity__r.id = : opp.id 
                                Order BY gmod__Year__c, gmod__Month__c asc];
        //Iterate through each list to extract the values and add it to the custom wrapper data type  

        PartMap = new Map < String, Decimal > ();
        Quarter1 = new Map < String, Decimal > ();
        Quarter2 = new Map < String, Decimal > ();
        Quarter3 = new Map < String, Decimal > ();
        Quarter4 = new Map < String, Decimal > ();
        Amount1 = new Map < String, Decimal > ();
        Amount2 = new Map < String, Decimal > ();
        Amount3 = new Map < String, Decimal > ();
        Amount4 = new Map < String, Decimal > ();

        for (gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c oppforecast: opflist) {

            String prodName = oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name;
            String monthText = oppforecast.gmod__Month_Text__c;

            Map<String, Decimal> quarterMap;
            Map<String, Decimal> amountMap;

            if (monthText == 'Jan' || monthText == 'Feb' || monthText == 'Mar'){
                quarterMap = Quarter1;
                amountMap = Amount1;
            if (quarterMap.containskey(prodName)) {
                quarterMap.put(prodName, quarterMap.get(prodName) + oppforecast.gmod__Quantity__c);
                amountMap.put(prodName, amountMap.get(prodName) + oppforecast.gmod__Amount__c);
            } else {
                quarterMap.put(prodName, oppforecast.gmod__Quantity__c);
                amountMap.put(prodName, oppforecast.gmod__Amount__c);
                wrapperclass w = new wrapperclass();
            w.gmod_Opportunity = oppforecast.gmod__Opportunity__r.Name;
            w.gmod_Product = prodName;
            w.gmod_Quantity = oppforecast.gmod__Quantity__c;
            w.gmod_Price = oppforecast.gmod__Price__c;
            w.Name = oppforecast.Name;
            w.gmod_Quarter = oppforecast.gmod__Quarter__c;
            w.gmod_Month = oppforecast.gmod__Month__c;
            w.gmod_Amount = oppforecast.gmod__Amount__c;
            w.Actual_Price = oppforecast.Actual_Price__c;
            w.gmod_Year = oppforecast.gmod__Year__c;
            w.gmod_date = oppforecast.gmod__date__c;
            w.gmod_Month_Text = monthText;
            w.Forecast_Date = oppforecast.Forecast_Date__c;
            disp_list.add(w);
        }
       }         
            if (monthText == 'Apr' || monthText == 'May' || monthText == 'June'){
                quarterMap = Quarter2;
                amountMap = Amount2;
                if (quarterMap.containskey(prodName)) {
                quarterMap.put(prodName, quarterMap.get(prodName) + oppforecast.gmod__Quantity__c);
                amountMap.put(prodName, amountMap.get(prodName) + oppforecast.gmod__Amount__c);
            } else {
                quarterMap.put(prodName, oppforecast.gmod__Quantity__c);
                amountMap.put(prodName, oppforecast.gmod__Amount__c);

                }
                }
            if (monthText == 'Jul' || monthText == 'Aug' || monthText == 'Sept'){
                quarterMap = Quarter3;
                amountMap = Amount3;
                if (quarterMap.containskey(prodName)) {
                quarterMap.put(prodName, quarterMap.get(prodName) + oppforecast.gmod__Quantity__c);
                amountMap.put(prodName, amountMap.get(prodName) + oppforecast.gmod__Amount__c);
            } else {
                quarterMap.put(prodName, oppforecast.gmod__Quantity__c);
                amountMap.put(prodName, oppforecast.gmod__Amount__c);
            }
            }
            if (monthText == 'Oct' || monthText == 'Nov' || monthText == 'Dec') {
                quarterMap = Quarter4;
                amountMap = Amount4;
                 if (quarterMap.containskey(prodName)) {
                quarterMap.put(prodName, quarterMap.get(prodName) + oppforecast.gmod__Quantity__c);
                amountMap.put(prodName, amountMap.get(prodName) + oppforecast.gmod__Amount__c);
            } else {
                quarterMap.put(prodName, oppforecast.gmod__Quantity__c);
                amountMap.put(prodName, oppforecast.gmod__Amount__c);


          /*  wrapperclass w = new wrapperclass();
            w.gmod_Opportunity = oppforecast.gmod__Opportunity__r.Name;
            w.gmod_Product = prodName;
            w.gmod_Quantity = oppforecast.gmod__Quantity__c;
            w.gmod_Price = oppforecast.gmod__Price__c;
            w.Name = oppforecast.Name;
            w.gmod_Quarter = oppforecast.gmod__Quarter__c;
            w.gmod_Month = oppforecast.gmod__Month__c;
            w.gmod_Amount = oppforecast.gmod__Amount__c;
            w.Actual_Price = oppforecast.Actual_Price__c;
            w.gmod_Year = oppforecast.gmod__Year__c;
            w.gmod_date = oppforecast.gmod__date__c;
            w.gmod_Month_Text = monthText;
            w.Forecast_Date = oppforecast.Forecast_Date__c;
            disp_list.add(w);*/
        }
}
            for (Quote qt: q) {
            System.debug('Quote Size ++ '+q.size());
             System.debug('opp forcast ++ ' +opflist.size());
                for (integer i = 0; i < opflist.size(); i++) {
               // if(Quarter1)
                    subtotalofquantity += integer.valueOf(opflist[i].gmod__Quantity__c);
                    System.debug('subtotalofquantity*%%%%%%%%% ++ ' +subtotalofquantity);
                    subtotalofamount += integer.valueOf(opflist[i].gmod__Amount__c);
                    System.debug('subtotalofamount*************** ++ ' +subtotalofamount);
                    //subtotalofamount =tempsubtotalofamount;
                    //Integer Colquarter1subtotalTemp = integer.valueOf(opflist[i].gmod__Quantity__c);
                    // Colquarter1subtotal += Colquarter1subtotalTemp;
                   //  System.debug('Colquarter1*************** ++ ' +Colquarter1subtotal);
                   // Integer quarter2subtotalTemp = Integer.valueOf(opflist[i].gmod__Quantity__c);
                   // quarter2subtotal += quarter1subtotalTemp;

                    //Instantiating the wrapper SObject     
                    wrapperclass w = new wrapperclass();
                    //Assigning the wrapper variables from the SObject Fields in the database.     
                    w.gmod_Opportunity = opflist[i].gmod__Opportunity__r.Name;
                    w.gmod_Product = opflist[i].gmod__Product__r.Name;
                    w.gmod_Quantity = opflist[i].gmod__Quantity__c;
                    w.gmod_Price = opflist[i].gmod__Price__c;
                    w.Name = opflist[i].Name;
                    w.gmod_Quarter = opflist[i].gmod__Quarter__c;
                    w.gmod_Month = opflist[i].gmod__Month__c;
                    w.gmod_Amount = opflist[i].gmod__Amount__c;
                    w.Actual_Price = opflist[i].Actual_Price__c;
                    w.gmod_Year = opflist[i].gmod__Year__c;
                    w.gmod_date = opflist[i].gmod__date__c;
                    w.gmod_Month_Text = opflist[i].gmod__Month_Text__c;
                    w.Forecast_Date = opflist[i].Forecast_Date__c;
                }//End of For loop int
            }//End of For loop Quote
        }//End of For loop gmod
        for(gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c oppforecast1 : opflist) {
         integer j = 0;

    for(j=0; j<3; j++){

    // replace oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name[i] with the product name string
    Integer Qty01 = Integer.valueOf(Quarter1.get(oppforecast1.gmod__Product__r.Name));
    Integer Qty02 = Integer.valueOf(Quarter2.get(oppforecast1.gmod__Product__r.Name));
    Integer Qty03 = Integer.valueOf(Quarter3.get(oppforecast1.gmod__Product__r.Name));
    Integer Qty04 = Integer.valueOf(Quarter4.get(oppforecast1.gmod__Product__r.Name));
    Integer Qty11 = Integer.valueOf(Quarter1.get(oppforecast1.gmod__Product__r.Name));
    Integer Qty12 = Integer.valueOf(Quarter2.get(oppforecast1.gmod__Product__r.Name));
    Integer Qty13 = Integer.valueOf(Quarter3.get(oppforecast1.gmod__Product__r.Name));
    Integer Qty14 = Integer.valueOf(Quarter4.get(oppforecast1.gmod__Product__r.Name));
    Integer Qty21 = Integer.valueOf(Quarter1.get(oppforecast1.gmod__Product__r.Name));
    Integer Qty22 = Integer.valueOf(Quarter2.get(oppforecast1.gmod__Product__r.Name));
    Integer Qty23 = Integer.valueOf(Quarter3.get(oppforecast1.gmod__Product__r.Name));
    Integer Qty24 = Integer.valueOf(Quarter4.get(oppforecast1.gmod__Product__r.Name));

    System.debug('qty@@@@@@@@@@@@@123 ++ ' + QtyGrndTtl);

    Qrtr1QtyGrndTtl = 0 + Qty01 + Qty11 + Qty21; //reset to zero each yr.
    Qrtr2QtyGrndTtl = 0 + Qty02 + Qty12 + Qty22;
    Qrtr3QtyGrndTtl = 0 + Qty03 + Qty13 + Qty23;
    Qrtr4QtyGrndTtl = 0 + Qty04 + Qty14 + Qty24;
    QtyGrndTtl[j] = Qrtr1QtyGrndTtl + Qrtr2QtyGrndTtl + Qrtr3QtyGrndTtl + Qrtr4QtyGrndTtl;

     System.debug('qty@@@@@@@@@@@@@ ++ ' + QtyGrndTtl);



    // replace oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name[i] with the product name string
    decimal amt01 = Amount1.get(oppforecast1.gmod__Product__r.Name);
    decimal amt02 = Amount2.get(oppforecast1.gmod__Product__r.Name);
    decimal amt03 = Amount3.get(oppforecast1.gmod__Product__r.Name);
    decimal amt04 = Amount4.get(oppforecast1.gmod__Product__r.Name);
    decimal amt11 = Amount1.get(oppforecast1.gmod__Product__r.Name);
    decimal amt12 = Amount2.get(oppforecast1.gmod__Product__r.Name);
    decimal amt13 = Amount3.get(oppforecast1.gmod__Product__r.Name);
    decimal amt14 = Amount4.get(oppforecast1.gmod__Product__r.Name);
    decimal amt21 = Amount1.get(oppforecast1.gmod__Product__r.Name);
    decimal amt22 = Amount2.get(oppforecast1.gmod__Product__r.Name);
    decimal amt23 = Amount3.get(oppforecast1.gmod__Product__r.Name);
    decimal amt24 = Amount4.get(oppforecast1.gmod__Product__r.Name);

    Qrtr1AmtGrndTtl = 0 + amt01 + amt11 + amt21; //reset to zero each yr.
    Qrtr2AmtGrndTtl = 0 + amt02 + amt12 + amt22;
    Qrtr3AmtGrndTtl = 0 + amt03 + amt13 + amt23;
    Qrtr4AmtGrndTtl = 0 + amt04 + amt14 + amt24;
    AmtGrndTtl[j] = Qrtr1AmtGrndTtl + Qrtr2AmtGrndTtl + Qrtr3AmtGrndTtl + Qrtr4AmtGrndTtl;

     System.debug('amt############# ++ ' +AmtGrndTtl);

    j++;

}

Decimal GrndAmtGrndTtl = AmtGrndTtl[0] + AmtGrndTtl[1] + AmtGrndTtl[2];
Integer GrndQtyGrndTtl = QtyGrndTtl[0] + QtyGrndTtl[1] + QtyGrndTtl[2]; 

        }
    }//End of disp


    //Declare a wrapper class      
    public class Wrapperclass  {
        //custom wrapper datatype      
        Public string Name{get;set;}  
        Public string AccountType{get;set;}  
        Public date todaysDate{get;set;}  
        Public date Expected_Order_Date{get;set;}
        Public string Probability{get;set;}  
        Public string Internal_Comment{get;set;}  
        Public string External_Comment{get;set;}      
        Public string Segment{get;set;}  
        Public string Application{get;set;}  
        Public string Persona{get;set;}  
        Public string Geogrpahy{get;set;}      
        Public string PartNumbers{get;set;}  
        Public Decimal  Price{get;set;}  
        Public Decimal End_Customer_Price{get;set;}  
        Public Decimal Quantity {get;set;}  
        Public Decimal Total{get;set;}      
        Public string RFQ_justification{get;set;}  
        Public string Main_Customer_of_Account{get;set;}  
        Public string Bridgelux_competition_at_account{get;set;}
        Public string Geographic_regions_serviced{get;set;}  
        Public string Annual_lighting_revenue{get;set;}  
        Public string Annual_LED_revenue_or_percent{get;set;}  
        Public string Annual_purchases_of_LED_light_sources{get;set;}
        Public string Percent_of_LED_purchases_that_are_COB{get;set;}  
        Public string Other_information{get;set;}      
        Public string Product_Series{get;set;}  
        Public string Volume{get;set;} 
        Public string Date_Price_is_Valid{get;set;}     
        Public string gmod_Opportunity{get;set;}
        Public string gmod_Product{get;set;}
        Public Decimal gmod_Quantity{get;set;}
        Public Decimal gmod_Price{get;set;}
        Public Decimal gmod_Quarter{get;set;}
        Public Decimal gmod_Month{get;set;}
        Public Decimal gmod_Amount{get;set;}
        Public Decimal Actual_Price{get;set;}
        Public Decimal  gmod_Year{get;set;}
        Public Date gmod_date{get;set;}
        Public string gmod_Month_Text{get;set;}
        Public Date  Forecast_Date{get;set;}
    }
  //  }
```

Comment: `QtyGrndTtl` has no elements so when j = 0 you get that error. Can you show the part of your code where you initialize `QtyGrndTtl`?

Comment: @ BarCotter:I have update the code .Any help very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Empty lists do not function the same as empty arrays.

An empty list must be added to using the `add()` method rather than assigning indexes directly. You can then use the array index style notation to directly modify the values that you have added to the list.

```
List<Integer> ints = new List<Integer>();
ints.add(7); // ints is now { 7 }
ints.add(3); // ints is now { 7, 3 }

ints[0] = 1; // ints is now { 1, 3 }
ints[1] = 1; // ints is now { 1, 1 }
ints[2] = 0; // List index out of bounds: 2
```

When using fixed sized arrays you can declare them to be a certain size and then assign to any element as you please at that point.

```
Integer[] ints = Integer[2]; // ints is now { null, null }

ints[1] = 1; // ints is now { null, 1 }
ints[0] = 7; // ints is now { 7, 1 }
ints[2] = 0; // List index out of bounds: 2
```

To fix your issue you can **either** change the line you mentioned to use the `add()` method:

```
QtyGrndTtl.add(Qrtr1QtyGrndTtl + Qrtr2QtyGrndTtl + Qrtr3QtyGrndTtl + Qrtr4QtyGrndTtl);
```

**Or**, since you know you'll always have 3 values you can switch to using a fixed sized array to store them instead, which lets you keep your assignment the way it is:

```
Integer[] QtyGrndTtl = new Integer[3];
```

Comment: :The array size is not fixed.For an example im using the size.But still tried it throws an Error at same Error at line{ Decimal GrndAmtGrndTtl = AmtGrndTtl[0] + AmtGrndTtl[1] + AmtGrndTtl[2];}.When i changed the Decimal to integer ,it throws another error as illegal assignment from  decimal to integer.Can u let me know how to use the add method.Any help very much appreciated.